# deconstruct an array and reconstruct it using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an 2D array

```
$artists = [
    ["name" => "Post Malone", "song" => "Circles", "genre" => "Pop"],
    ["name" => "Camila Cabello", "song" => "Liar", "genre" => "Pop"],
    ["name" => "Tones and I", "song" => "Dance Monkey", "genre" => "Alternative"],
    ["name" => "Billie Eilish", "song" => "Bad Guy", "genre" => "Alternative"],
];
```

I'm trying to write a function that organized the array by genre and group different artist by genre. My output should looks like this:

```
array (
  'Pop' =>
  array (
    0 => 'Post Malone',
     1 => 'Camila Cabello',
   ),
  'Alternative' =>
   array (
     0 => 'Tones and I',
     1 => 'Billie Eilish',
   ),
)
```

I have tried to construct the outter array first

```
function organizer($artists) {
    $genre = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($artists); $i++) {
        $outterArr = array_push ($artists[$i]["genre"],$genre);
        return $outterArr;
    }


}
```

But stuck on how to construct an new array inside the outer array.
I'm very new to programming and php. please bare my skill, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/array_reduce) to group your entries by genre:

```
$artistsByGenre = array_reduce($artists, static function ($byGenre, $artist) {
  $byGenre[$artist['genre']][] = $artist['name'];
  return $byGenre;
}, []);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/3fU83**

Answer (score 0):

```
function group_by($key, $data) {
    $result = array();

    foreach($array as $val) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $val)){
            $result[$val[$key]][] = $val;
        }else{
            $result[""][] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $result; }

$genres = group_by("genre", $artists);
```